# Getting a list of productSKUs into one field in Bigquery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am wrangling with a query in Google bigquery and hope someone can help.

Desired Output Columns:

visit id - ecommerce_actiontype - sku_list

example:
visit id: 123
ecommerce_actiontype: 6
sku_list: [SKU1,SKU2,SKU3]

I have tried the following two queries:

1)

```
SELECT
visitid,
eCommerceAction.action_type as ecommerce_actiontype,
(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(productSKU) from UNNEST(hits.product)) AS sku_list
FROM `test.1234.ga_sessions_*` as t, t.hits as hits, hits.product as p
```

This doesn't put the productSKUs into one list grouped by visitid and ecommat.

2)

```
SELECT
visitid,
eCommerceAction.action_type as ecommerce_actiontype,
ARRAY_AGG(productSKU) AS sku_list
FROM `oval-unity-88908.97547244.ga_sessions_*` as t, t.hits as hits, hits.product as p
```

This gives me the error "Error: SELECT list expression references column visitid which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [16:1]"

Anyone have any idea how to achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
SELECT 
  visitid,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT ecommerceAction.action_type act_type, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT productSku IGNORE NULLS) skus_list FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(product) GROUP BY 1) data
FROM `test.1234.ga_sessions_*`
```

The main difference between this query and yours is that it avoids using the outer `UNNEST` on the `hits` field which helps later on to aggregate on for each `visitId` all the ecommerceActions and the skus associated with them.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have schema details for ga_sessions tables but try below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  visitid,
  eCommerceAction.action_type AS ecommerce_actiontype,
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(product.productSKU) FROM UNNEST(t.hits) WHERE NOT product.productSKU IS NULL) AS sku_list,
  ARRAY(SELECT product.productSKU FROM UNNEST(t.hits) WHERE NOT product.productSKU IS NULL) AS sku_list2
FROM `test.1234.ga_sessions_*` AS t
```

as you can see - I presented two options for construction needed array - `ARRAY_AGG` within `SELECT` and `ARRAY(SELECT`

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into it. Unfortunately I get an error message "Cannot access field productSKU on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<productSKU STRING, v2ProductName STRING, v2ProductCategory STRING, ...>> at [20:28]" if I try this, marking "product.productSKU". Any idea?

Comment: I also tried 

SELECT
visitid,
ARRAY(SELECT productSKU FROM UNNEST(hits.product))  AS sku_list2

FROM `test.1234.ga_sessions_*` as t, t.hits as hits

but this gives me the error UNNEST expression references hits.product which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [21:39]